# Finite Elements: using preconditioned conjugate gradients with incomplete cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, iterative-method

I have to write a little finite elements code in C.

I was asked to implement the conjugate gradients method, which I have done. Now, I am looking to improve further the efficiency of my program by using the Incomplete Cholesky Decomposition.

As I understand it, instead of solving the $ Ax = B $ system, I have to solve the $ M^{-1} Ax = M^{-1}B$ system where matrix $M$ is the incomplete Cholesky decomposition of matrix $A$.

However, when I tried to implement this, I found that computing $M$ and then inverting it was more expensive in time than simply using the CG method.
I suppose I must have done something wrong, but I really don't see how PCG with Cholesky is implemented.

Comment: Note that you don't ever want to compute $M^{-1}$ explicitly.  Rather, turn each expression involving $M^{-1}$ times a vector into the solution of a system of equations with $M$ as the matrix.

Comment: Also, that's not how you implement a preconditioned CG method. Have you even looked at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method)? (To reiterate Brian's comment: You'd solve $Mz_{k+1}=r_{k+1}$ using backward and forward substitution based on the incomplete Cholesky factors, not invert and apply anything.)

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean/how to do it in practice.
Moreover, computing M (using Cholesky's incomplete decomposition) takes as much time as directly solving $Ax = B$ when I tried it.

Comment: I have looked up the Wikipedia page yes. However, my main problem is computing M and finding some way to invert it in a cheap and efficient way.

Comment: You never compute $M$ directly, that's the whole point -- you compute an incomplete Cholesky factorization of $A$, which you can invert (factor by factor) *very* cheaply. That's your $M^{-1}$, if you will. Of course, the threshold value for the fill-in is a parameter you have to tune for your specific problem -- if you choose poorly, you indeed won't see any speed-up.

Comment: Being pretty much a beginner in this domain, is there any place you could link me to that would show me how to implement this efficiently in C ?

Comment: Sorry, no; I can tell you about the mathematics, but the programming language-specific implementation is not my forté (nor strictly on-topic here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77402/discussion-between-gilles-poncelet-and-christian-clason).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While preconditioned CG with incomplete Cholesky (ICC) is reasonably straightforward to formulate mathematically, writing an *efficient* implementation is a non-trivial matter.

Here's some of the things that would make for an efficient implementation:

- the ICC implementation exploits the sparsity of your matrix $A$ (you'll want to store $A$ and $M$ in some sparse matrix format)
- $M$ is computationally "easy" to invert (you won't compute the actual inverse $M^{-1}$, just its action on a vector)
- you set appropriate hyper-parameters for the ICC algorithm (e.g., block size, levels of fill-in, zero threshold) and (pre-)allocate memory space for $M$ accordingly
- miscellaneous optimizations (e.g., the *Eisenstat trick*, see the paper by Chan)
- code optimizations that target your specific hardware platform (I won't go into specifics here).

At the end of the day, what you're after is a preconditioned iteration that converges *faster* (in some objective measure) than its un-preconditioned counterpart.

References to get you started:

> Yousef Saad, [Iterative methods for sparse linear
>   systems](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf) -
>   in particular chapters 9.2, 9.2.1 and 9.2.2 deal with the preconditioned
>   CG iteration (there is some pseudocode that you can base your initial implementation on).
>
> Chan and van der Vorst, [*Approximate and Incomplete
>   Factorizations*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2291679_Approximate_And_Incomplete_Factorizations)
>   (they discuss incomplete LU and its variants, but the ideas there
>   apply to ICC as well).
>
> Chih-Jen Lin and Jorge J. Moré, [Incomplete Cholesky Factorizations
>   with Limited
>   Memory](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1064827597327334), SIAM SISC 21(1), 1999

Some high-quality C/C++ ICC implementations (these libraries have a fairly steep learning curve, but the source code is available for inspection):

> PETSc's [ICC routines](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ksp/pc/impls/factor/icc/icc.c.html#PCICC).
>
> [IFPACK](https://trilinos.org/packages/ifpack) (part of the Trilinos
>   suite). The user manual can be found [here](http://trilinos.org/oldsite/packages/ifpack/IfpackUserGuide.pdf).
>
> Eigen's [C++ ICC preconditioners for CG](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1IncompleteCholesky.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just got a few extra question: 1)what do you mean by ‘action vector exactly? I’m afraid that’s pretty unclear to me and 2) what is the block size you mentioned?

Comment: **(1)** by _action on a vector_ I mean the product $M^{-1}v$ for a given vector $v$, that is equivalent to solving the linear system $Mx = v$ for $x$ (again, you do _not_ compute the inverse explicitly).

Comment: **(2)** to take advantage of fast cache memory (maximize _data reuse_), numerical algorithms are often _blocked_ - see [here](http://algowiki-project.org/en/Cholesky_method#The_Cholesky_decomposition:_a_block_version_for_sparse_real_symmetric_positive_definite_matrices). the optimal block size is dependent on your target architecture. this is an advanced optimization topic that is best ignored at the beginning.

Comment: and I suppose the $Mx = v$ system is super cheap to solve? Which ‘techniques’, if any, are used ?

Comment: Well the icc factor $M$ is (upper) triangular (and very sparse) so you can solve that system using backsubstitution